# Set Organization wide Address in report

Tags: apex, email

I am Trying to set Organization wide Address as from address in report. But I don't see any option there.

I am sending email alert on schedule report, Any suggetion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organization-Wide Address is used to send out the email alert from the Workflow rule not for the Report.

For Report, it will be the user email address who has subscribed or scheduled the report run in the future.

I would recommend scheduling it with the user whose email is similar to the Org Wide email address.

[image]